# Virtual registry to Windows XP

Tags: virtualization, registry

What options for registry virtualization exist that will work with all Windows versions starting from XP? Basically what I need is a way to hijack some registry reads for a particular application and returned "virtualized" values.

Something that might add to the complexity of the solution need is the fact that this application can spawn additional processes, which also need to be virtualized.

Comment: You might start at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965884%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: You might start by reading the question. I need this for Windows XP.

Comment: Where in @Rafe's link does it say it doesn't work with WinXP?

Comment: @JamWaffles - second line in the article, "It is supported starting with Windows Vista."

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that there is no readily available Registry virtualization APIs or framework in Windows XP. You need to build one by making use of user mode or kernel mode Registry API hooks. Some approaches are:
 - User mode hooking of RegXxxx APIs by using SDKs like Microsoft Detours or MadCodeHook.
 - Kernel mode hooking (SSDT or inline) of ZwXxx or NtXxx APIs. Sysinternals Regmon and now Sysinternals Process Monitor does this to monitor system-wide Registry calls.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one solution - to use boxedapp. it's sdk for creating virtual registry. It must help you. Goodluck.

Comment: Great suggestion. I had a problem with an app that needs to launch from the user's LocalLow directory and also access the registry for storing its preferences (hint: that doesn't work), and virtualizing the registry keys in question with BoxedApp solved my problem. Thanks!